# Wicket - Custom Page Navigation in DataTable

Tags: java, navigation, wicket

I've got a DataTable with a a BottomToolbar.

```
DataTable<Example> exampleTable = new DataTable<Example>("exampleTable", columns, provider, 10);
exampleTable.addBottomToolbar(new NavigationToolbar(exampleTable));
```

Right now i have the normal navigation (<< < 1 2 3 > >>). I want to achieve a feature like this: [image]

So i have a) the normal page navigation: << < 1 2 3 > >> and b) the Go To Field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method in the Class Datatable

```
   public final void setCurrentPage(final long page) {
        datagrid.setCurrentPage(page);
        onPageChanged();
    }
```

in combination with an AjaxFormSubmitBehaviour on a TextField, like this:

```
textfield.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehaviour("onkeyup or some other event") {

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        datatable.setCurrentPage(Long.parseLong(textfield.getModelObject()));
        target.add(datatable);
    }
})
```

The 'textfield' component being the textfield where you can enter your page number.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I ended up using a custom BottomToolbar which extends NavigationToolbar and used the method newPagingNavigator with a custom PagingNavigator.